# C# Date Conversion From Euro Time To en-US Time Needed For Date Calculations

Tags: c#, .net, string, date

I have a date that is entered through the system (from a database) as `dd/mm/yy` I need to programmatically convert the date to `en-US` format to `mm/dd/yyyy` so that I can do some date calculations within the code. The code that I have so far is:

```
String myJames = "25/04/13" // Date String comes in as non-US date

String myJames2 = System.DateTime.Today.ToString(myJames); // I think the problem is here

DateTime d1 = Convert.ToDateTime(myJames2);
DateTime d2 = DateTime.Now;

TimeSpan t = d2 - d1;
double NrOfDays = t.TotalDays;
```

I know this is not completely correct, especially in the first few lines. Any help getting the dates into one en-US format for effective comparisons would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, but sample makes no sense - you are passing "25/01/13" as format specification for `DateTime.ToString` call... Not sure what you expect as result.

Comment: Actually the value from the database comes in that format. I just listed it that way for simplification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to check I understand your question.  You have a date as a string and you want to convert that string into a datetime so you can use it in a calculation?  And your problem is that the string isn't in the format that the locale the code is running in would use?

In which case use DateTime.ParseExact.

```
DateTime d1 = DateTime.ParseExact(myJames,"dd/MM/yy");
```

This line of code would replace your line declaring and assigning d1.  The line assigning to myJames2 can be removed as it isn't needed.

Answer (score 1):

Everytime you convert from or to a string, culturesettings are involved.

So.. if you are converting a DateTime to string, and your culture is en-US, it will automatically converted to: MM/dd/YYYY.

This is also true for converting back. If you convert a string back to a DateTime, the culturesettings are used to see what format the string is in.

Teh culture settings are always: Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.

Most conversion functions allow to override the format (like "MM/dd/yyyy") and/or the culture. So you can create your own culture and use this during conversions.

You say the database uses dd/MM/yy, but normaly a DateTime in a database is not formatted, it is just a binary value. Or is it stored as a text? If it is stored as a text, than you should ALWAYS convert it to a DateTime using the correct culture or format.